# Car that I drive regularly has flat battery, bad alternator?

Tags: battery, alternator, battery-drain, cranks-wont-run

A car that I pretty regularly drive everyday has just had it's battery run flat.

I had just got back from a 30 minute drive and 10 minutes later tried to turn it on and it just kept cranking like a flat battery.

I haven't noticed any weaker engine starting but I guess I may have not noticed.

Because I drive regularly and haven't noticed weak engine start recently could this mean the alternator has gone bad?

Edit
I have since tried charging the battery and had no luck and have realised thanks to a comment that that was irrelevant anyway.

Edit 2
The car is an 1998 Nissan Pulsar N15 Manual

Comment: A flat battery will not provide enough power to crank an engine. Are you saying that the engine will turn over but not start?

Comment: How old is the battery?

Comment: Not sure on the age of the battery but the engine does the over just doesn't catch

Comment: A flat battery doesn't have power to crank, so you won't hear nothing.

A weak battery will crank, but not strong enough. The sound of the weak, insufficient, cranking is easily distinguishable from normal cranking.

If you are hear the ordinary, strong, cranking, but the engine won't start, the fault is somewhere else.

Comment: @Martin yeah I agree I feel pretty silly for not realising what the engine cranking meant. One thing I can think of is the distributor is currently leaking oil and has been for quite a while. Due to this I noticed that the cable coming from the distributor and going underneath has has its cable casing caked in oil

Comment: @VehicularIT even better, then you already have a strong candidate for the fault

Comment: @Martin anyway to go about testing it? Other than just replacing the cable?

Comment: I have no experience on distributors, sorry. I suspect the distributor itself being damaged. An separate question on this site might be your best choice. Just one advice: Write down what cylinder is attached to what distributor plug/position. A mix-up can drive one crazy.

Comment: More information is needed. Does it crank? Does it crank but not start? How old is the battery? One can't further diagnose without a fully-charged battery in place.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica it does crank and is cranking pretty strong not weak at all. Unsure on age of the battery, am I able to read that on the battery?

Comment: And I've given the battery a charge with a battery charger and am getting the same cranking but the engine just won't catch

Comment: Please identify the manufacturer, model, engine type, and year of the vehicle.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica  The car is an 1998 Nissan Pulsar N15 Manual

Comment: If it has an OBD-II port (all US cars do, and some non-US ones as well), you should use a code reader to see what error codes might be displayed or stored.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120947/discussion-between-davidsupportsmonica-and-vehicular-it).